# How to determine $u\times (v \times w)$ is determined by the plane made by $v$ and $w$ via some geometric way

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to determine $u\times (v \times w)$ is determined by the plane made by $v$ and $w$.  Of course i assume that $u, v, w$ are not zero vectors.

Of course i know BAC-CAB rule, and know how to prove it. (Using symbolic or doing some explicit computation) But here what i want to do is understand its geometric perspective.

I want to know some geometric way, $i.e$, using the fact like $v\times w$ is perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$, etc.

I found relevant resource on Anton's Linear algebra textbook and their problem solution but that's not enough for me.  I captured them as follow

---

we know that the vector v × w is perpendicular to both v and w.
Hence v × w is perpendicular to every vector in the plane determined by v and w;
moreover the only vectors perpendicular to v × w which share its initial point must be in this plane. But also note that u × (v × w) is perpendicular to v × w for any vector u ≠ 0 and hence must lie in the plane determined by v and w.

---

Can you give me some more detail explanation or give some alternative explanations for me?

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{u}\times(\underline{v}\times {w})$ is the vector co-planar with $\underline{v}$ and $\underline{w}$ which is perpendicular to $\underline {u}$.

Comment: Quinn, Of course i know the meaning, what I want to know is how $u \times (v\times w)$ is the vector copalnar with $v$ and $w$. Can i accept that as a definition?

Comment: @phy_math: $v\times w$ is perpendicular to the plane containing $v$ and $w$ and any vector which is perpendicular to the normal of this plane must be parallel to the plane